# host with default gateway as itself

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

I am facing a peculiar problem. Earlier we had 4 network segments in our production setup, say segment A,B,C and D. A,B and C are able to communicate with each other,the corporate lan and the internet. Segment D is completely isolated segment and purely used for backup and management. so a host Z only on segment D was not able to access any of the other segment.

We recently introduced vmvare vsphere 5.1 setup in our production environment. We have created a distributed switch in vcenter. The distributed switch has uplinks from all the 4 network segments. We have created separate port group for each segment as well.

Now the problem is the host D is now able to communicate with other segments, but only those in the vmware setup, ie hosts attached to the distributed switch. Physical machines in other segments are still not accessible by machine Z.

Now this is my analysis of the problem.

1. Checking the host Z, if found the the default gateway was set as host Z itself.
2. A vsphere distributed switch behaves like an L2 switch and port groups are just a group of ports and does not mark any isolation between them.
3. Since the default gateway is maintained, there is path in the host Z routing table for all other segments. ie the packets reach the D segment switch[point 1].**The switch is then sending these packets through the uplinks to the vsphere distributed switch**, Keeping point 2 in mind, the packets reaches the destination host.

Point 3 is where I am confused[specifically, the part which is **bolded**], may be due to my less knowledge in the networking side. Since for machine Z, the gateway is itself, any packet sent for other segments should return to itself....!!.??..or I know that there is something called the spanning tree protocol, which prevents looping in the network. Is this coming into play....?? How is the packet reaching my distributed switch....??

Please correct me if any of the points are wrong and many thanks in advance.

Comment: Spanning Tree prevents traffic storms when you connect multiple switches together: A to B, B to C, and then C back to A, by detecting the presence of a physical loop and automatically blocking one of those three paths to prevent the switches from forwarding the same traffic over and over in a circle... so that is unlikely to be related.  The default gateway isn't relevant if host Z has an IP address on the same subnet as other hosts, since the gateway is only used to reach hosts that are *not* on the same IP subnet.  Describing the IP subnetting scheme may be useful, here.

Comment: hai michael,  Thanks for the reply. A i mentioned in another comment, we have separate physical switches for the 4 segments. Routers are maintained for segments A,B and C and they can communicate with each other,corporate lan and internet. Switch for segment D is physically isolated. It is not connected to any router.  What i noticed is the moment i set default gateway of host Z as itself or any other machine's IP in segment D, its able to communicate to machines in other segment,but only those attached to the vmware VDS. Physical machine is other segments are still not accessible.

Comment: Physical machine is other segments are still not accessible. please note that host Z is attached only to segment D switch which has no routers connected to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last got the answer to my question. Its  was due to how Linux implelemts TCP/IP stack. By default it uses weak host model.[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model] . The Remote hosts  network adapter which was connected to the private network was responding to request on the ip of the other adapter due to this.

The host Z was always accessing the private network D only . As mentioned by sean,since the default gateway of Z was set to itself, it would try to sent packets directly to any other host, which supported the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your network is not actually segmented how you describe.  Is it possible that the distributed switch is using the same VLAN number for all port-groups or possibly not using VLANs at all?  If packets are not being VLAN tagged via the VDS, that would explain why there is undesired connectivity inside of vSphere, and that same connectivity is not observed on the physical uplinks.

It might be helpful to provide more details about IP/masking across your environment, as well as router interfaces to explain the segmentation in more detail.

In any case, I hope this much might be useful.  Good luck.

Comment: hai sean, thanks for the reply and you are correct. We are not using vlans. We have seperate switches for each segment. I m not clear how the packets are reaching the VDS at first place when the default gateway is the host Z itself.Any light on this..?

Comment: it is possible that the IP and netmask on host Z are set in a way that the host does not think it needs a gateway to reach the hosts on other segments.  the fact that you are not using VLANs means that the hosts within vSphere would be able to reach each other without a router, depending on how their IP/mask is configured.

Comment: the moment i remove the gateway setting on machine Z, its not able to communicate with other segments. This shows that, the gateway has something to do with the behavior. Yes, the hosts within vsphere are able to reach one another depending on their IP/MASK settings.

Comment: with a default route set to it's own interface, the server would attempt to send packets directly to any other hosts.  this is much like host Z having a mask that summarizes all of your networks.  again, it would be helpful for you to describe your subnet scheme.  since your virtual network is not segmented, there would be more going on at layer-2 than you might think.  to prevent cross-network communication, you would really want to assign VLAN numbers to the port-groups on your VDS, forcing hosts to go through their respective routers to reach other segments.

Comment: ok, thanks.  on host z, remove the default route and use a /16 mask.  the connectivity will still work because all networks are using a common (default) VLAN.  please tell me if this works.

Comment: i guess you didn't say what network D is, so I should not have assumed.  if it is another 10.72.X.X network, then my last comment should work.

Comment: sorry sean, i didnt want to disclose the details but accidental posted it. I can add that A,B and C are /24 networks and D is a /21 network. The host Z has only one interface card with D segment IP. Its routing table contains an entry for the D segment and not for any segments. I also noticed that if i change the gateway and set it as any other D segment ip in segment D in host Z, its still able to communicate to other segment machines in vmware setup.

Comment: do the /24 subnets A/B/C fall in the same range as the host z /21?  if that is the case, host z would attempt to directly access any address (no routing) on those subnets.

Comment: i think the possibily is something like yu suggested in your earlier post **"with a default route set to it's own interface, the server would attempt to send packets directly to any other hosts. this is much like host Z having a mask that summarizes all of your networks."**  Can you tell me why this might be happening....?? The same behaviour is observed when i set gateway as any other D segment IP. Is your suggestion applicable in this case also....??

Comment: no the /24 subnets A/B/C doesnot fall in the range of /21 segment

Comment: sorry, i cannot answer because i don't know how your other D segment IPs are being set.  fwiw, posting addresses and masks in private ranges is pretty low risk...  I have no way of accessing those networks unless I am already inside your environment.

Comment: sorry sean, my seniors are not allowing me to share the info. All other D segment IP are set in the same way as host Z

Comment: hai sean, i thnk as u said in your comment **with a default route set to it's own interface, the server would attempt to send packets directly to any other hosts. this is much like host Z having a mask that summarizes all of your networks** is what is happening. I checked the network packets using wireshark and saw the host Z sending an arp request for ip of the remote machine directly without first issuing an arp for the gateway(cleared arp cache first), and since the physical and DS was connected , the machine recivd the packet and responded. Its like the switches are being cascaded.plz sgst